# How to evaluate expression with provided parameters before running the report?

Tags: java, parameters, jasper-reports, expression, evaluation

I'm having the worst time trying to figure out, how to evaluate expressions with parameters from loaded JRXML file at runtime, before whole jasper PDF generation starts. So far, it works for simple expressions which doesn't need any parameters from outside. But I need to evaluate expression with given parameters.

Some working sample code in Java for evaluation without parameters:

```
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(jrxmlStream);
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

    DefaultJasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
    List<JRExpression> compiledExpressions = JRExpressionCollector.collectExpressions(jasperReportsContext, jasperReport);
    int size = compiledExpressions.size();
    JRExpression expression = compiledExpressions.get(size - 1);

    JREvaluator evaluator = JasperCompileManager.loadEvaluator(jasperReport);
    Object jasperEvaluatedValue = evaluator.evaluate(expression);
```

And now I'm stuck. This static API is not very friendly. Does anyone tried to evaluate expressions this way? When I do things "the standard way", letting jasper do his job and passing map of parameters to JasperFillManager:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

everything evaluates perfectly fine and my PDF output is correct. But I need to evaluate these expressions before that.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark (never attempted it) but looking at the `JREvaluator` it looks like you can initialize it with parameters, fields and variables.  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JREvaluator.html#init(java.util.Map,java.util.Map,java.util.Map,net.sf.jasperreports.engine.type.WhenResourceMissingTypeEnum,boolean) Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks, but I saw this and unfortunately I cannot create map of JRFillParameters (this method requires these kind of parameters) cause of protected constructor. I'm looking how to fetch these parameters from another JR objects, or convert somehow, but still haven't found the solution.

Comment: Not optimal, sorry I didn't look, but you could (if it's not final) just extend the class for the purpose of your testing (or whatever you're doing) making the protected constructor available?

Comment: It seems like a big spatula (or plan B). There must be a legit way to pursue this issue. It doesn't even feel like very complicated scenario, I'm just trying to provide some parameters before evaluation. Jasperreports API is just hard to read.
But I will remember your suggestion :)

Comment: I agree with you 100% but looking through the code (quickly) there isn't anything that I can see other than taking advantage of `protected`.  Sorry guy.

Comment: Can you take advantage of a `Scriptlet` in order to inject those variables at the appropriate time?  Your initial question sounds like you need to do the evaluations BEFORE the report is even run.  But if you're just injecting them during the running of the report, you can inject a scriptlet?

Comment: But isn't the `Scriptlet` on the report side? I mean, you must include these Scriptlet classes in the JRXML file, right? I cannot do that - I'm receiving final JRXMLs and generating pdfs in ma java app

Comment: Can you give a better example of what you're actually trying to inject?  I was under the impression that you were just writing some tests.  But you're attempting to inject LIVE data into a running report so it's there when the Expression is about to be run?  What kind of data do you need to get in there that isn't already available from Properties and coded in the JRXML?

Comment: Ok, sure. So I'm gonna receive JRXMLs from external source and I'll not be able to interfere in these JRXML files. I need to evaluate expressions (at runtime) under <imageExpression> tag before report-filling phase and replace these filepaths with something else (let's say a link to resource). Jasper reports creation is happening on different host then PDF generation so filepaths vary.

Comment: If you need to evaluate at runtime, you need to either use a Scriptlet (known to JRXML developer) or apply some kind of class to the Parameters (which still need to be known to the JRXML developer so they use something like `$P{image_parser}.getImagePath($F{something})`.  But evaluating expressions before you run FillReport isn't going to do anything, unless you're using that value to set a parameter prior to running the report `$P{file_path}` or something like that.  But if the JRXML has hard coded file paths, I don't think you can alter those in the compiled jasper.  This is out of my league

Comment: I understand. Well, thank You for trying. It may end up as impossible task after all and I will have to change approach. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with a way to evaluate expressions with parameters by looking at the source of [JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/15a3228f9003af4da8666abde9b1d5cc47c309b9/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.java#L74)

The code would look something like this:

```
JRFillObjectFactory factory = new JRFillObjectFactory((JRBaseFiller) null, null) {
    @Override
    public JRFillGroup getGroup(JRGroup group) {
        return super.getGroup(null);
    }
};
JRDataset reportDataset = jasperReport.getMainDataset();
JRFillDataset fillDataset = factory.getDataset(reportDataset);

fillDataset.createCalculator(jasperReport);
fillDataset.initCalculator();
fillDataset.setParameterValues(map);

Object jasperEvaluatedValue = fillDataset.evaluateExpression(expression, JRExpression.EVALUATION_DEFAULT);
```

Alternatively you could put the expression in the report as a parameter default value expression, and directly use [JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/fill/JRParameterDefaultValuesEvaluator.html#evaluateParameterDefaultValues(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,java.util.Map)) to evaluate parameter default values and extract the evaluated expression from the result.